# How to keep particular sessionScope variable(s) in use and remove the other sessionScope variable(s)?

Tags: xpages

The application allows the user to search and the result displays in the other page

For example search.xsp is for user to fill information to search and searchresult.xsp is for display the search result.

In search.xsp and searchresult.xsp, I use sessionScope variable to perform search function.

The search function is something like this:

```
var qstring= "";
if ((sessionScope.ItemSearch != null && sessionScope.ItemSearch != "")||(sessionScope.CategorySearch != null && sessionScope.CategorySearch != "")|| (sessionScope.LocationSearch != null && sessionScope.LocationSearch !=""))
{
    qstring = " FIELD Item contains " + sessionScope.ItemSearch +
    " | FIELD Category contains " + sessionScope.CategorySearch +
    " | FIELD Location contains " + sessionScope.LocationSearch
}
return qstring;
```

In the searchresult.xsp, I add a back button that will return to the search.xsp.
I read the user requirement, when the user clicks the back button, it will redirect the user to the search.xsp but the previous selection should be cleared.

To clear the sessionScope variable, I found this code from this website
https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=clear-session-current-nsf

```
clearMap(sessionScope);
//facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("./?logout");

// Clear Map function
function clearMap( map:Map ){ // Get iterator for the keys
    var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();  // Remove all items 
    while( iterator.hasNext() ){  
         map.remove( iterator.next() ); 
          }
}
```

I applied the code in search.xsp in afterPageLoad event so when I click the back button, the search.xsp will remove my previous search selection.

Here is my question.

On top of every page, there is a computed field which shows the user's login role. The reason needs to show the user's role is the user will have multiple roles in the application and I created another page to let user to choose the role that the user wants to login as.

Here is the code of that computed field

```
var selectrole =sessionScope.role;
if(selectrole == "Common User")
{
    return "You logged in as Common User role";
}
else if(selectrole == "Senior User")
{
    return "You logged in as Senior User role";
}
else if(selectrole == "Manager")
{
    return "You logged in as Manager role";
}
else if(selectrole == "Administrator")
{
    return "You logged in as Administrator role";
}
else
{   
}
```

Due to I use sessionScope variable to show user role, so if the user goes to the search.xsp and perform the search function, when the user the clicks the back button in searchresult.xsp. The clear sessionScope function will also remove sessionScope.role's value.

I searched on the internet about clear specific sessionScope variable but it seems not much information on this issue

Since the clear  sessionScope variable works fine, I tried to remove specific sessionScope variable.

```
clearMap(sessionScope.ItemSearch);
//facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("./?logout");

// Clear Map function
function clearMap( map:Map ){ // Get iterator for the keys
    var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();  // Remove all items 
    while( iterator.hasNext() ){  
         map.remove( iterator.next() ); 
          }
}
```

At the beginning, I think it is hard to remove specific sessionScope variable, and the result comes as no surprise for me that I get the error.

So is there any possible method that I can keep particular sessionScope variable(s) in use and clears the other sessionScope variable(s)?

Or any better approach for this case?

Grateful for your advice please. Thank you

Comment: I would like to thank you Paul Stephen Withers and Knut Herrmann's answer. Although I can only accept one answer, I upvote both anwsers because they suit my application.

Comment: About the sessionScope, I have a strong feeling that I will need to use a lot of sessionScope variables in the application in the furture and some of them I need to keep the values until the session time out and some of them I have to clear immediately. So is it fine in xpage development? I mean will the server take more resources to run the code? Since I am not server administrator so I am worry I will crash the server one day if I use many sessionScope variables in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please bear in mind what the code you link to is doing. The first line is logging the user out of HTTP completely. The rest is going through `sessionScope` and, for every key, removing that variable from the `sessionScope` map of variables.

I added that snippet to replace a simple logout button, because if a user just logs out of HTTP, then logs in as a different user, they (by default) retain the same `sessionScope` variables, because `sessionScope` is *browser* session, not *user* session.

It sounds like you don't want that snippet. Instead you just want to clear a specific `sessionScope` variable. `sessionScope.remove("myKey")` will do that, where `myKey` is the sessionScope variable key.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I use the code for the logout button in the application too. Before I receive the solution from this post, I notice if I comment this code `facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("./?logout");` can also remove sessionScope variable, so I apply it in the application. I know it is not a good practice but I don't have idea how to remove particular sessionScope variable at that moment.
Now I will keep in mind that _sessionScope is browser session, not user session_. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: May I ask a question please? I tried `sessionScope.remove("myKey")` and it works.  I would like to know what is the difference between `sessionScope.remove("myKey")` and `sessionScope.myKey= "";`? Both of those code can clear the sessionScope.

Comment: `.remove()` removes the variable completely. `myKey=""` will mean the variable is there, but its value is a blank string. XPages Debug Toolbar on OpenNTF is a great resource for inspecting scoped variables, as well as other debugging functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set search's sessionScope variables to an empty string

```
sessionScope.ItemSearch = "";
sessionScope.CategorySearch = "";
sessionScope.LocationSearch = "";
```

This keeps the other sessionScope variables alive and your search form is cleared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask a question please? I tried your code and it works.  I would like to know what is the difference between `sessionScope.remove("myKey")` and `sessionScope.myKey= "";`? Both of those code can clear the sessionScope.

Comment: .remove() removes the variable from sessionScope map. It will be created again when you open search.xsp. `= ""` just empties the variable. It stays in sessionScope map and has an empty string as value. It does not have to be created again when you open search.xsp. It might be a millisecond faster than .remove() :)